# How get data from url on android

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

I used ImageLoader libs show image from url. It's run normal until it get data from a url by korean format. I handled by asyntask, or encode unicode utf8, but all is fail. It can't get data from this url format.

Url origin:
[http://dazone.crewcloud.net/MailAttach/1/_CrewChat/AttachFile/0/635927107253177274/명치명치.png](http://dazone.crewcloud.net/MailAttach/1/_CrewChat/AttachFile/0/635927107253177274/%EB%AA%85%EC%B9%98%EB%AA%85%EC%B9%98.png)

Url unicode utf8 name:
http://dazone.crewcloud.net/MailAttach/1/_CrewChat/AttachFile/0/635927107253177274/%EB%AA%85%EC%B9%98%EB%AA%85%EC%B9%98.png

My code:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(new Prefs().getServerSite() + url, view, Statics.options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view2, FailReason failReason) {
                String name = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, s.lastIndexOf("."));
                String type = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("."));
                String query = null;
                try {
                    query = URLEncoder.encode(name, "utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String urlNew = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("/")+1)+query+type;
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(urlNew))
                {
                    LoadImage loadImage = new LoadImage(view);
                    loadImage.execute(new String[]{urlNew});
                }
                    //ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(urlNew,view, Statics.options2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view2, Bitmap bitmap) {
                view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {

            }
        });
```

LoadImage.java
public class LoadImage extends AsyncTask {

```
private ImageView imageView;
public LoadImage(ImageView imageView) {
    this.imageView = imageView;
}

@Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap map = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            map = downloadImage(url);
        }
        return map;
    }

    // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                    decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I didnt used any lib to load image from uri but i have write code to load image and save in memory cache, Create class as per below -

------------ImageLoader.class--------



  package com.example.test;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.WeakHashMap;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import com.example.test.R;

    public class ImageLoader {

        // Initialize MemoryCache
       public MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();

        public FileCache fileCache;

        //Create Map (collection) to store image and image url in key value pair
        private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections.synchronizedMap(
                                               new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
        ExecutorService executorService;

        //handler to display images in UI thread
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        public ImageLoader(Context context){

            fileCache = new FileCache(context);

            // Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of
            // threads operating off a shared unbounded queue.
            executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        }

        // default image show in list (Before online image download)
        final int stub_id= R.drawable.ic_launcher;

        public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
        {
            //Store image and url in Map
            imageViews.put(imageView, url);

            //Check image is stored in MemoryCache Map or not (see MemoryCache.java)
            Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);

            if(bitmap!=null){
                // if image is stored in MemoryCache Map then
                // Show image in listview row
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else
            {
                //queue Photo to download from url
                queuePhoto(url, imageView);

                //Before downloading image show default image
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }
        }

        private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
        {
            // Store image and url in PhotoToLoad object
            PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);

            // pass PhotoToLoad object to PhotosLoader runnable class
            // and submit PhotosLoader runnable to executers to run runnable
            // Submits a PhotosLoader runnable task for execution 

            executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
        }

        //Task for the queue
        private class PhotoToLoad
        {
            public String url;
            public ImageView imageView;
            public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
                url=u;
                imageView=i;
            }
        }

        class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
            PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

            PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
                this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    //Check if image already downloaded
                    if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                        return;
                    // download image from web url
                    Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);

                    // set image data in Memory Cache
                    memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);

                    if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                        return;

                    // Get bitmap to display
                    BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);

                    // Causes the Runnable bd (BitmapDisplayer) to be added to the message queue.
                    // The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.
                    // BitmapDisplayer run method will call
                    handler.post(bd);

                }catch(Throwable th){
                    th.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }





        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
        {
            File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

            //from SD cache
            //CHECK : if trying to decode file which not exist in cache return null
            Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
            if(b!=null)
                return b;

            // Download image file from web
            try {

                Bitmap bitmap=null;
                URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
                conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();

                // Constructs a new FileOutputStream that writes to file
                // if file not exist then it will create file
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);

                // See Utils class CopyStream method
                // It will each pixel from input stream and
                // write pixels to output stream (file)
                Utils.CopyStream(is, os);

                os.close();
                conn.disconnect();

                //Now file created and going to resize file with defined height
                // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
                bitmap = decodeFile(f);

                return bitmap;

            } catch (Throwable ex){
               ex.printStackTrace();
               if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                   memoryCache.clear();
               return null;
            }
        }

        //Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
        private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){

            try {

                //Decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
                stream1.close();

              //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.

                // Set width/height of recreated image
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE=1085;

                int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
                int scale=1;
                while(true){
                    if(width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                        break;
                   /* width_tmp/=2;
                    height_tmp/=2;
                    scale*=2;*/
                    width_tmp = 510;
                    height_tmp = 310;
                 }

                //decode with current scale values
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize=scale;
                FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
                Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
                stream2.close();
                return bitmap;

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){

            String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
            //Check url is already exist in imageViews MAP
            if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
        class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
        {
            Bitmap bitmap;
            PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
            public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
            public void run()
            {
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;

                // Show bitmap on UI
                if(bitmap!=null)
                    photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                else
                    photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }
        }

        public void clearCache() {
            //Clear cache directory downloaded images and stored data in maps
            memoryCache.clear();
            fileCache.clear();
        }

    }


-------------------FileCache.class -----------------

package com.example.test;

import java.io.File;
import android.content.Context;

public class FileCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context){

        //Find the dir at SDCARD to save cached images

        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                                     android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        {
            //if SDCARD is mounted (SDCARD is present on device and mounted)
            cacheDir = new File(
                       android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
        }
        else
        {
            // if checking on simulator the create cache dir in your application context
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        }

        if(!cacheDir.exists()){
            // create cache dir in your application context
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    public File getFile(String url){
        //Identify images by hashcode or encode by URLEncoder.encode.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());

        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear(){
        // list all files inside cache directory
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return;
        //delete all cache directory files
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}


----------------------MemoryCache.class--------------

package com.example.test;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;

public class MemoryCache {

    private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";

    //Last argument true for LRU ordering
    private Map<String, Bitmap> cache = Collections.synchronizedMap(
            new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f,true));

   //current allocated size
    private long size=0;

    //max memory cache folder used to download images in bytes
    private long limit=1000000;

    public MemoryCache(){

        //use 25% of available heap size
        setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/4);
    }

    public void setLimit(long new_limit){

        limit=new_limit;
        Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to "+limit/1024./1024.+"MB");
    }

    public Bitmap get(String id){
        try{
            if(!cache.containsKey(id))
                return null;

            return cache.get(id);

        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
        try{
            if(cache.containsKey(id))
                size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
            cache.put(id, bitmap);
            size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
            checkSize();
        }catch(Throwable th){
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        Log.i(TAG, "cache size="+size+" length="+cache.size());
        if(size>limit){

            //least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated
            Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();

            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
                size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                iter.remove();
                if(size<=limit)
                    break;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size "+cache.size());
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        try{
             // Clear cache
            cache.clear();
            size=0;
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(bitmap==null)
            return 0;
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}


----------------------Utils.class------------------

package com.example.test;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Utils {
    public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
    {
        final int buffer_size=1024;
        try
        {

            byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
            for(;;)
            {
              //Read byte from input stream

              int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
              if(count==-1)
                  break;

              //Write byte from output stream
              os.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}

-----To load image from uri write following code -----------

ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    String  img = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/SchApp/e1e5cf55-2f4b-467a-987e-155a708eaefe_bg.JPEG";
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(MainActivity.this);

     imageView1.setTag(img);    
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(img, imageView1);
```

Comment: Thanks you! but my problem is url korean format. With url aren't this format, my code loading normal. But when have url korean format, it can't decode inputstream from data of url.